# Phaser 3 + Firebase Can't Access Array Outside Call To Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, phaser-framework

I make a call to a Firebase Firestore database. I push the results into an array.
I output the results to console. However, I am unable to access the data (line 48) in the array even though it is there (line 45) as per image below. What could I be doing wrong?

```
        var collectSnap = new Array()
       var collectionRef = db.collection("players").get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {       
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
                var docData = doc.data()
                collectSnap.push(docData);
                
            })
            return collectSnap
        })
        .catch(function(error){ console.log("error!", error)})

       console.log('collectSnap', collectSnap)

       for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           console.log(i + ' : ' + collectSnap[i])
       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the data in an asynchronous function call, but trying to access it synchronously (before the server has actually responded).

Try something like this:

```
function runWhenReady(players) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        console.log(i + ' : ' + players[i])
    }
}

db.collection("players").get()
    .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
    .then(runWhenReady);
```